# Meaning of government-run in paragraph?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Could anyone guide me the meaning of *government-run* in below paragraph?

> Until the late 1980s, cannabis and opium were legal in India, sold in **government-run** shops and traded by the British East India Company.

I think it's mean government authorized or government owned. Any expert could guide me on this?

Comment: It's a hyphenated attributive noun phrase meaning "run by the government" so yeah, controlled and operated by the government.

Answer (score 1):

The term "government-run" pretty much means what it says -- run by the government.  Of course, the devil is in the details, so one cannot say with any certainty whether the meaning is

- Owned and operated by a government agency, with government employees running it.
- Run by a private party as a sort of franchise of the government, reporting all transactions to the government, and perhaps obtaining "product" from the government.
- Run by a private party and simply conforming to some government-prescribed rules.